# Replace nth line in a r file

Tags: r

This is how to replace the 3rd line in a txt file. How do you do this in an R file?

```
> latin = readLines("junk.txt",-1)
> latin[3]="per ardua ad astra"
> writeLines(latin,"junk.txt")
```

Here is an example of an R file.

```
fxGetRate <- function(s,c) {
  x <- s*c
  return(x)
  
}

# s <- 10
# c <- 50
# fxGetRate(s,c)
```

I may want to change line 2 to

```
x <- s + c
```

This is hypothetical to a much larger R file. Thank you in advance.

```
latin = readLines("C:/Users/xxx/Documents/r/x/lib.R",-1) #error on this line
latin[2]="x <- s + c"
writeLines(latin,"C:/Users/xxx/Documents/r/x/lib.R")
```

This is the error.

```
Warning message:
In readLines("C:/Users/xxx/Documents/r/x/lib.R", -1) :
  incomplete final line found on 'C:/Users/xxx/Documents/r/x/lib.R'
```

Comment: I modified the question to include an ex thank you.

Comment: An "R file" `.r` is just text - I don't see why your current code wouldn't work.

Comment: That is not an error but a warning. Did you open and see the file after running the code? It works for. me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code worked when I opened the file. The error was just a warning. Thank you both!